# "except:" not catching all errors

Tags: python

I was working on a project to give a score to vulnerabilities (CVSS) discovered based on their CVEID.
For that purpose I used the restAPI of the NIST but I'm getting errors that are most likely due to the format of the response. For debugging purposes I wanted to ignore all errors and see which requests didn't go through
So I used a try, except block but they are still errors.

Here is my code :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from urllib import request
import json
from time import sleep

basecolumn = 13
baseline = 1


wb = load_workbook('vulnerabilities.xlsm',keep_vba=True)
ws = wb['CISA Last CVE']
wb.save('Test2.xlsm')

CVEID = "temp"
lineCounter = 0
while CVEID is not None: # While they are vulnerabilities to scan
    lineCounter +=1
    line = baseline+lineCounter
    CVEID = ws.cell(row=line,column=1).value
    if ws.cell(row=line,column=basecolumn).value is None: # Checks if CVE was already scanned previously
        with request.urlopen("https://services.nvd.nist.gov/rest/json/cve/1.0/"+str(CVEID)) as response:
            print(str(CVEID))
            html = response.read()
            responseCVE = html.decode('utf8').replace("'", '"') # Converts to JSON
            responseJSON = json.loads(responseCVE)
            try:
                exploitability = responseJSON['result']['CVE_Items'][0]['impact']['baseMetricV2']['exploitabilityScore']
                impact = responseJSON['result']['CVE_Items'][0]['impact']['baseMetricV2']['impactScore']
            except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
                print("first try not working")
                exploitability = responseJSON['result']['CVE_Items'][0]['impact']['baseMetricV3']['exploitabilityScore']
                impact = responseJSON['result']['CVE_Items'][0]['impact']['baseMetricV3']['impactScore']
            except:
                print("Mistery error")

            #print(exploitability)
            #print(impact)
            ws.cell(row=line,column=basecolumn).value = exploitability
            ws.cell(row=line, column=basecolumn+1).value = impact
            sleep(10)
    else :
        print("Already scanned " + str(CVEID) +" vulnerability")
        print(ws.cell(row=line, column=basecolumn).value)
    wb.save('Test2.xlsm')
```

And here is the error I'm getting no matter the [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeiGM.png) I try to raise

Edit : Wow, that was such a dumb error, sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score 1):

From reading the error I see you missplaced the `responseJSON = json.loads(responseCVE)` line. Just put it inside the `try` block.

```
try:
    responseJSON = json.loads(responseCVE)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is where the error occurs.

```
            responseCVE = html.decode('utf8').replace("'", '"') # Converts to JSON
            responseJSON = json.loads(responseCVE)
```

The try- except block comes after this. This means, exceptions within `json.loads` do not get caught.

Answer (score 0):

The error is an line 30

`responseJSON = json.loads(responseCVE)`

It is out of the try/catch part.

try to put it after the try: